# how to detect a view is a native or web page?

Tags: ios, webkit

when I open an app, I want to know how the app implement one view in it. but I don't know how to detect the view is a native view or a web page, please tell me how to detect it.

Comment: Are you asking how someone else implemented a screen in their app?

Comment: [How to Inspect the View Hierarchy of Third-Party Apps](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-3rd-party-apps/). You will need a jailbroken device for this.

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you:

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
    //view is a UIWebView
}
```

Comment: What if you do not have access to the source code of the application?